# Son los números adjetivos o sustantivos?

Tags: gramática

Que tipo de palabras son los números? (Por ejemplo diez (10) ) Son los números sustantivos o adjetivos?

Comment: En el Diccionario de la Lengua Española probalemente tengas la respuesta: http://www.rae.es/ (más en concreto: http://dle.rae.es/?id=DinuHtF)

Comment: Pablo: la pregunta es interesante, pero no muestra investigación alguna. Esto nos chirría en este sitio, por lo que sería interesante que le dieras a [edit] para añadir qué buscaste antes de preguntar. Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La mayoría de los números cardinales pueden ser adjetivos, sustantivos o incluso pronombres.

> ¿Sabes cuál es mi número favorito?  Es el **diez**<sub>(sustantivo)</sub>.
>
> — ¡Qué coincidencia!  Tengo aquí **diez**<sub>(adjetivo)</sub> libros.
>
> ¡Hala! ¿Y son todos buenos?
>
> Pues, no.  **Cinco**<sub>(pronombre)</sub> son excelentes, pero los demás son pésimos.

Los números partitivos solo se usan como sustantivos o adjetivos, y hoy en día casi siempre como sustantivos salvo en algunos casos como *medio* que sigue disfrutando de mucho uso como tal.  Los números muy altos (*millón*, *billón*, etc) funcionan solo como sustantivos.

Los números ordinales, en contraste, se pueden usar como adjetivos (lo normal), adverbios (principalmente con números inferiores), o a veces sustantivos (aunque casi siempre por sustantivarse):

> Hoy, **primero**<sub>(adverbio)</sub> vamos a hablar de la **Primera**<sub>(adjetivo)</sub> Guerra Mundial.  No abráis el libro al último capítulo que estudiamos, sino al **primero**<sub>(adjetivo sustantivado)</sub>, que es el que trata de esa guerra.